# Storing open windows / forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

i have an interactive graph on my main form, when you click a child on the graph a new window opens showing specific data for that child.

I want to try and have a way of on the right of my main form docking these opening windows in to a container of some sort (like a list view) and providing the user a scroll left and right through open windows to see what they have open. This would form a type of cache too (in my head at least!)

is this possible, maybe like a listview of open windows or something? and if so what do i need to research? i guess for starters my main form would need a panel for the interactive graph and a panel for the dock on the right?

What else can you recomend i research.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis sounds like a MDI UI look at this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp11272005225843PM/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp.aspx